# Can I require a module specifically for iOS in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am currently using [`react-native-safari-view`](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view) module in my React Native project for showing web views in iOS.

As the module is not yet implemented for Android, when I try to build the project for Android, it gives me an error at this line:

```
import SafariView from 'react-native-safari-view'
```

I am going to use the [`Linking`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) library for Android, but I don't know how to use the same code for two platforms.

I tried:

```
if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
    import SafariView from 'react-native-safari-view'
}
```

And it gives me this error:

> import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 15):

To get around this I have been using `require` instead (but mainly for modules rather than components):

```js
var SafariView;

if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
    SafariView = require('react-native-safari-view');
}
```

For this particular situation I would definitely go for Konstantin Kuznetsov's approach - Just sticking this here as it might help someone else where making a wrapper component with separate files may be overkill :)

Comment: I had to add `.default` to the end of the import in my case. In this case it would be: `SafariView = require('react-native-safari-view').default;`

Comment: but I couldn't achieve this with 
var BackgroundTimer;

if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
    BackgroundTimer = require('react-native-background-timer').default;
}

error say... timeout is undefined when using ....
const timeoutId = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {

Comment: to help someone importing things which are not exported as default: let TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity;
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    ({ TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity } = require('react-native-gesture-handler'));
} else {
    ({ TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity } = require('react-native'));
}

Answer (score 10):

platform-specific code is more complex, you should consider splitting the code out into separate files. React Native will detect when a file has a .ios. or .android. extension and load the relevant platform file when required from other components.

For example, say you have the following files in your project:

```
BigButton.ios.js
BigButton.android.js
```

You can then require the component as follows:

```
import BigButton from './BigButton'
```

reference 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions

Answer (score 5):

You can separate platform code by creating two different files `your_file_name.android.js` and `your_file_name.ios.js`. So you can create two versions for the file where you want to use `SafariView` or you can create a wrapper around `SafariView` which will export this module on iOS and dummy object on Android, and then use this wrapper with `Platform.OS` checks.